# With (Q's) deferred.resolve, can I see where the resolve ends up returning the value to?

Tags: javascript, promise, q

Trying to digest an app that wasn't my code, and is currently failing.

I'm wondering if there's an easy way to find out where the deferred.resolve(value) pops up in the code without tracing into Q library?

Meaning, given code like this:

```
getSomething = function() {
  var deferred = Q.defer();

  someOtherPromise().then(function(somevalue) {
    deferred.resolve(somevalue); //can I see what .then is about to get called with somevalue?
  })

  return deferred.promise;
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "see"

Comment: Install https://www.npmjs.com/package/bluebird-q and use it instead of Q with the adapter, run the code with `--inspect` in Node or open the devtools in Chrome - and put a breakpoint which will now contain async stack traces.

Comment: In modern standards Q is harder to debug than the alternatives, I say that as a maintainer - prefer native promises or bluebird.